# Specifying a layout file for devise gem in rails (what does this do?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I know how to specify a layout file for devise. But **what I don't understand is how this works**. Specifically, in the code below my `layout_name_for_devise` is used if it's a devise controller. So then I figured this must mean the "application" layout would be used if it's NOT a devise controller (which in my case is in `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`). Now, I have other layouts, for example one called `home`. I thought my views using my `home` layout would break...but it turns out it work fine. **I don't understand how this works. For example, when the code below runs, how is it that my `app/views/layouts/home.html.haml` layout still gets called correctly?**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "layout_name_for_devise"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

A good nights rest does wonders for the brain. So I woke up understanding how this works...but also feeling silly for not seeing it earlier.

**tl;dr** - *this code is inside the `application` controller. Other controllers don't call this code. That's why it works correctly.*

**Longer Answer:**

Rails tries to find layouts based on the controller name. If a layout doesn't exist then rails will use the `application` layout.

So in my `Home` controller rails first looks for a `home` layout. Since there is one it uses that layout.

I'm not sure what devise does but it's not looking for a layout named `devise` so instead it uses `application` layout. And that's when the code above runs. Since the controller is a devise controller the layout then gets changed to "layout_name_for_devise".

Comment: Just go ahead and accept your own answer :) Thanks for the info by the way!